# NoMethodError: undefined method `to_csv' for ["a", "b"]:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Why is this new Rails project having a problem finding the `to_csv` method?

I'm running Ruby v2.1.3, installed with `rbenv`. There is no reason whatsoever for it not to find this method.

I have another project running v2.1.0 where I make heavy use of `to_csv` on array objects. No problems there.

Comment: Did you remember to `require "csv"`?

Comment: Put in an answer! You are correct, of course. I had it in application.rb of my other app, so I missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget to require the CSV module:

```
require "csv"
```